# Salesforce Connection

Tags: 8, crm

I am currently getting an error when trying to connect Drupal 8 with Salesforce. This will be the first time I am hooking into Salesforce from Drupal and I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. I am using the Salesforce Suite Module.

I get the following errors while creating a new authentication provider? (Not on a local environment so Salesforce can see the URL.)

> Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\salesforce_jwt\Plugin\SalesforceAuthProvider\SalesforceJWTPlugin::$credentials in Drupal\salesforce\SalesforceAuthProviderPluginBase->getCredentials() (line 194 of modules/contrib/salesforce/src/SalesforceAuthProviderPluginBase.php).

> Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key in Firebase\JWT\JWT::sign() (line 209 of /home/client-name/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php).

> OpenSSL unable to sign data

Does anyone know where I could start looking or can provide insight into what these errors mean? I have been stuck on this a few days and I can't seem to find anything helpful yet in my research.

The undefined property makes me think that I may be missing a dependency; however, this is a complete guess.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue and am putting the answer here.

There were two issues that I needed to address:

1. The database was using RDS on AWS and I needed to enable the "log_bin_trust_function_creators" parameter group
2. Add TRIGGER privilege for database web user

I hope this helps someone else out there with a similar issue.